# wordpress change menu as per website section

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress so don't know if I am asking a bad question. I am working on a umbrella website for a company which have 5 company's under it. you can say this is a mother site.

What we are trying to accomplish is when a user comes to main site. we want a menu but if use goes to a company site under it. we want to change the menu as per the company.

**Main Website Menu**
Home | About us | Company 1 | Company 2 | Company 3 .........and so on

**Company 1 Menu**
Home | About Company 1 | Products | HR | Contact us | Back to Main Site

**Company 2 Menu**
Home | About Company 2 | Admission | Careers | Online Demo |Contact us | Back to Main Site

and for rest of 5 companys.

I know Wordpress allow to create multi menu. how to change menu as it goes from company to company.

Regards
Moksha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to modify your theme with some custom menus, check out

http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel

and

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/